# How to use jquery val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

html:

```
<div>
  <div style='margin-top: 30px' class='form-group align-items-center'> 
    <form> 
      <input name='test-id' class='form-control' id='test-id' type='text'>
    </form> 
  </div> 
  <div id='form-button' type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Submit</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('click', '#form-button', function(e) {
   console.log($("#test-id").val())
 }) 
})
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/vorousjames/pen/PoNramd?editors=0001

logs "" instead of the value.

Why does this not work

Comment: Works for me on the codepen you provided.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the functionality. It's logging the values as expected. Did you make sure that you typed something in the input box before clicking `Submit`?

Comment: Downvoted, the provided example works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The console log is working fine. When there is no value inside the text box, it will obviously give "" as output. Although it's obvious and no change is required, the snippets as the answers did not seem right to me, so I am posting of how that should be done.

To prevent the submission of `form` on pressing `enter`, `event.preventDefault()` is used.
Besides that, if you want the code to generate output only when there is some value insides the textbox, you fetch the value, trim it using `trim()`, which removes whitespaces, check if it's empty("" yields false), and console log, only if it's not empty.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#form-button', function(event) {
  let val = $("#test-id").val().trim();
  if (val) {
    console.log(val);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div style='margin-top: 30px' class='form-group align-items-center'>
    <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
      <input name='test-id' class='form-control' id='test-id' type='text'>

      <button id='form-button' type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The codepen you link to works for me. It logs "" if the `input` element you are calling `val()` on is empty. If you type something into it first, then click Submit, it will output something other than "".

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does log correct value when you **click** on it.

Most likely you are **pressing enter** and as your input is inside form, pressing enter will submit the form which is why you are seeing empty string.

You need to fix your form, just to demonstrate, I have added `return false` to form's submit method to avoid form submission.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#form-button', function(e) {
    console.log($("#test-id").val())
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div style='margin-top: 30px' class='form-group align-items-center'>
    <form onsubmit="return false">
      <input name='test-id' class='form-control' id='test-id' type='text'>
    </form>
  </div>
  <button id='form-button' type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Correct form should be something like:

```js
function checkValues() {
  console.log($("#test-id").val())
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div style='margin-top: 30px' class='form-group align-items-center'>
    <form onsubmit="checkValues(); return false;">
      <input name='test-id' class='form-control' id='test-id' type='text'>

      <button id='form-button' type='submit' class='btn btn-danger'>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't work on clicking button. That is because, the button is not `submit` type. Have a look at my anwer.

Comment: @PranavRustagi I have two examples explaining what is wrong with OP's code, one as it and another working.

Comment: Type something in textbox and click the "submit" button. You'll know what I am talking about :)

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I forgot to set type submit on second example.